# Why is Ron still wearing a bandage if Hermione's spell closed the open wound?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1* (2010), Ron got injured after Apparating, so Hermione treated him with a spell.
Yet afterwards he is still shown wearing a bandage: why so?

[image: Sad Ron]

Comment: Technically, she cured him with Essence of Dittany which is not a spell. Carry on.

Comment: Looks like a sling, not a bandage. But the question remains…

Comment: @JonCuster is correct.  That is a simple sling, not a bandage.  One may assume the wound is closed but orthopedic damage remains.  Is there is direct evidence for this from movie or book?

Comment: @DoscoJones the sling seems like evidence enough :p

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The wound was closed using Essence of Dittany but it's not a complete solution...so there is still damage to the arm.

> Harry wrenched the stopper off the little bottle, Hermione took it and poured three drops of the potion onto the bleeding wound. Greenish smoke billowed upward and when it had cleared, Harry saw that the bleeding had stopped. The wound now looked several days old; new skin stretched over what had just been open flesh.
>
> “It’s all I feel safe doing,” said Hermione shakily. “There are spells that would put him completely right, but I daren’t try in case I do them wrong and cause more damage. . . . He’s lost so much blood already. . . .”
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - J.K. Rowling

So although the immediate problem has been solved his arm is still not completely healed so a sling (not a bandage) is required

Comment: Worth noting that there is an existing example of a spell that *could* put him completely right, but its [demonstration of it proved that you could, in fact, get them wrong and cause more damage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160333/why-did-lockharts-spell-stop-at-the-arm).